# VSTS build ended with empty build artifacts

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are using VSTS build using ASP.Net template. We are passing MSBuild Arguments as below-

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true
>   /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
>   /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
>   /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
>   /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"

We see no build error. From the log we observe a line -

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /LRM -p ..\LRM\ -u -f -d PrecompiledWeb\LRM\

where LRM is the .NET sln name which we are building. This sln contains multiple projects along with the LRM website.

At the end of the build pipeline we see no artifact generated. We see a warning at the "Publish Build Artifacts" saying -

> 2018-01-03T06:07:47.9208838Z ##[warning]Directory 'D:\VSTS Agents\DEV-QAS\A1\66\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.

Answer (score 4):

Use below as msbuild arguments (/p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)" is the diffrence)

```
/p:TransformConfigFiles=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)"
```

Use Publish task Path to publish as "$(build.stagingDirectory)\_PublishedWebsites" if you only want the website output. If all the files in staging directory required use "$(build.stagingDirectory)" as path to publish

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause, but perhaps this alternative set of MSDeploy-targeted MSBuild parameters will prove to be a workaround.

```
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployTarget=Package /p:PackageTempRootDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
```

Comment: Tried with that configuration. But same empty directory at **..\a**

Answer (score 0):

It is the website, so you can’t publish it as the web application.

First, as **ChamindaC** said that you can specify **OutDir** argument, but it won’t generate the web deployment package, you can archive the folder to zip through Archive task. (Note: the value should be `/p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)\\"`)

Secondly, it can generate the **publishproj** file once creating publish profile (right click website > Publish Web App). So you can specify that file in **Visual Studio Build** or **MSBuild** task with your MSBuild Arguments to publish website to web deployment package.

Comment: Can you please specify what should be the total MSbuild arguments in this case considering your first and second point

Comment: For the first way, `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)\\"`. For the second way, you can use the original argument as you said.

Comment: I am using the below MSBuild Arguments but without success ......  /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)\\" ..... Getting the below error while build........Error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share the sample project on the OneDrive.

Comment: @DimitryKhan What's the result now? Can you share a sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: Thanks @starian chen-MSFT for your comment.
We have to create a separate sample project to share. I will take some time for that.
However, as we observed that the problem is during compiling the project. It could not (or may be skipped) compilation thus produced no dlls and ended with empty artefacts. For now, we have added the source .cs files into the published artefacts and solved the problem temporarily.

Comment: You can share the detail build log first. (Using `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)\\"` arguments)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

ASP.Net Web API MSBuild Arguments: **/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)  /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true**

Publish Build Artifacts : 
Path to Publish: **$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)_PublishedWebsites**

The above configuration is working for me, please check the image for details.